# OOM when using solr DIH

Tags: lucene, solr, dataimporthandler

hi all:
    There is an OOM error when I using DIH to execute a full import command, The database is sql server 2008, and only 30k rows data in db, How do I fix it?
    Thanks in advance for any help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this entry in the DataImportHandler FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#I.27m_using_DataImportHandler_with_MS_SQL_Server_database_with_sqljdbc_driver._DataImportHandler_is_going_out_of_memory._I_tried_adjustng_the_batchSize_values_but_they_don.27t_seem_to_make_any_difference._How_do_I_fix_this.3F).

Comment: Hi Mauricio, thanks for your help. I've read the wiki, but another question is the importing speed is so slow if I use cursor to avoid OOM. There is 40 million data in db which I want to index, is there a better way to slove this problem?

Comment: @Illu: try writing the importing process yourself, instead of using DIH.